# T-SQL - SQL Server - Update records from ID_B based on ID_A

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've two dimension:

```
Permissions

- Permission_ID
- Permission_Desc

Users:

- User_ID
- User_Name
```

And one `Fact_Tables`:

```
- User_ID
- Permission_ID
- Salary_Amt
```

Now what I'm trying to make is apply the permission that User_ID 1 have to the User_2. Replicate the permissions of User_ID_1 to User_ID_2

How can I do that in an Update Statement?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick way would be to delete all permissions assigned to User_2. Then: 
`insert into Fact_Tables select 2, Permission_ID, Salary_Amt from Fact_Tables where User_ID = 1` assuming User_2 has ID = 2 and User_1 has ID = 1. I'm also assuming that User_2 should have the same `Salary_Amt` as User_1

Comment: Wouldn't a simple update work here?  `update fact_table set permission_id =  (select permission_id from fact_table where user_id = user_1_id) where user_id = user_2_id` ? What have you tried?

Comment: @Rigerta that wouldn't work as it seems to be a many-to-many relationship

Comment: @Rigerta the problems is that UserID_1 have more permissions (than Records) than User_ID_2. I run your query and I get the following issue:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @Petaflop nop, User_2 and User_1 don't have the same salary

Comment: @John_Rodgers then, what salary should User_2 have in the event that there's no record in `Fact_Tables` associated to him?.. NULL ? 0 ? what's your tables schema? Maybe mixing permissions and salary is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Not the efficient of ways, however, I think this should do the job provided I understood the question correctly:-

```
    Create Table #permissions (permission_id int, permission_desc 
    varchar(100))

    insert into #permissions values (1, 'select'),(2,'insert')

   Create Table #users (user_idd int, user_desc varchar(100))

   insert into #users values (1, 'John'),(2,'Rohn')

   Create Table #fact_table (user_idd int, permission_id int, sal int)

   insert into #fact_table values (1,1,200), (2,2,300)

   select * from #fact_table 
   update a set a.permission_id = b.permission_id from #fact_table a 
    inner join (
    select (select user_idd from #fact_table where user_idd=2) user_idd, 
   permission_id, sal from #fact_table where permission_id = 1
   ) b on a.user_idd=b.user_idd
```